# Signals and Systems - LTI - Transforms - Impulse Response

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, linear-systems

I have $x(t)-> LTI -> y(t)$ where $LTI=h(t),H(jw)$.

and

$H(jw)=ab/((a+jw)(b+jw))$ where a and B are real numbers.

I am wanting to find the impulse response $h(t)$ as well as the input/output differential equation to the system.

If my understanding is correct I would want to take the Fourier transform of the frequency response/input and I am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Please write a better title. The topic of this whole site is signals and systems. Your title **must** be more specific to your problem.

Comment: Okay. I'll update. First time posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$H(jw) = \frac{output}{input} = \frac{Y(jw)}{X(jw)}$$

$$\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} = \frac{ab}{(a+s)(b+s)}$$

$$s=jw$$

Then you can use some of the notions [from this example](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Transient/TransMethTF.html) to solve for your impulse response / differential equation. Hope that helps!

Comment: I assume I could also take the inverse Laplace in order to find h(t) correct?

Comment: Correct. the inverse laplace of H(s) will give  you h(t).